# edit frames from a video source before render c++

Tags: c++, video-processing

I need you to recommend me a library for c++ to use with visual c++ 2008 to perform an edition ef the frames from a video source before been rendered on the screen. I dont want to perform effects like blur or things like that, I want to change the size en some cases and other stuff.

I have tried with phonon (where I cant access the frames) and opencv (where I can get the frames but I cant display the audio because the library is for other purpose), I have been reading about directshow on windows but I still dont know if I can recover the frame.

Regards, Marco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/developer.html).  It's what OpenCV uses to read frames.

FFMPEG includes a simple player -- ffplay.  Have a look at its [source](http://cekirdek.uludag.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/ffplay_8c-source.html) for an idea of how to use the library.

Comment: Ffmpeg, and it's successor avconv, is based on the libav library, which is open-source and very popular, but it is also a PITA to the work with, has complicated options, and is full of quirks.

Answer (score 0):

As misha said FFMPEG is THE library for videoacquisition. As you use C++, you can try the simpler to use [FOBS](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/), which is a C++ encapsulation of FFMPEG. You can look at the sources if you want to do your own C++ wrap around FFMPEG.

my2c